# Наследование или добавление type поля?

Tags: классы, шаблоны-проектирования

В каких случаях вы бы стали наследовать класс, а в каких внедряли бы поле тип объекта?

Например:
"Импульсный" и "Цифровой" счетчик различаются по набору полей.
"Водяной счетчик" может быть как цифровым так и импульсным.

Однако чтоб получить "Водяной счетчик".data я должен поработать с полями импульсного счетчика или цифрового или интегрированного или... или ..

Напрашивается что-то вроде поля type в "Счетчик" тогда в коде можно оперировать с такими данными через switch, что сократит количество кода. Но тогда где определять эти "дополнительные" поля..

Постарался отобразить в коде суть вопроса.

```js
// TypeScript not works on stackoverflow.

// Первый пример
abstract class Counter {
  constructor(protected serialNumber: string) {}

  getData(data: number): number {
    return data;
  };
}

class ImpulseCounter extends Counter {
  constructor(
    private initCounter: number,
    private multipler: number,
    serialNumber,
  ) {
    super(serialNumber)
  }

  getData(data) {
    this.initCounter + this.multipler * data;
  }
}

class WaterImpulseCounter extends ImpulseCounter {
  constructor(
    private hot: boolean,
    initCounter,
    multipler,
    serialNumber
  ) {
    super(initCounter, multipler, serialNumber);
  }

  getData(data) {
    if (this.hot) {
      return this.super.getData(data) * 0.1
    } else {
      return this.super.getData(data)
    }
  }
}

class DigitalCounter extends Counter {
  constructor(
    private address: string,
    serialNumber
  ) {
    super(serialNumber)
  }

  getData() {
    this.super.getData();
  }
}

class WaterDigitalCounter extends DigitalCounter {
  constructor(private hot: boolean,
    address,
    serialNumber
  ) {
    super(address, serialNumber)
  }

  getData(data) { // Дублирование кода, тупик.
    if (this.hot) {
      return this.super.getData(data) * 0.1
    } else {
      return this.super.getData(data)
    }
  }
}



// Второй пример
enum DataTypes = {
  Impulse,
  Digital
}

abstract class Counter {
  constructor(
    protected serialNumber: string,
    protected dataType: DataTypes
  ) {}

  getData(data) {
    switch (this.dataType) { // В каком месте(классе) нужно определять switch логику и поля this.initCounter, this.multipler
      case (DataTypes.Impulse):
        {
          return this.initCounter + this.multipler * data;
        }
    }
    return data;
  };
}

class WaterCounter extends Counter {
  hot: false;
  constructor(
    serialNumber,
    dataType: DataTypes
  ) {
    super(serialNumber, dataType)
  }

  getData(data) {
    if (this.hot) {
      return this.super.getData(data) * 0.1
    } else {
      return this.super.getData(data)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Например: "Импульсный" и "Цифровой" счетчик различаются по набору полей. "Водяной счетчик" может быть как цифровым так и импульсным.

Пока это описание хрестоматийной мотивации использовать паттерн «Декоратор»:

```
class WaterCounter extends Counter {
  constructor(
    private impl: *Counter
    hot: bool
    serialNumber,
  ) {
    super(serialNumber)
  }
  getData(data: number): number {
    data=impl->data;
    return this.hot ? data * 0.1 : data;
  };
}

//...

waterImpulseCounter = new WaterCounter(new ImpulseCoubter(..., 0), hot, serial);
digitalImpulseCounter = new WaterCounter(new DigitalCoubter(..., 0), hot, serial);
```

Но тут во-первых непонятно, что делать с серийником внутренних классов, а во-вторых немного страдает логика поведения: теперь возможно создать водный счётчик, который может использовать другой водный счётчик, так что помня основное правило, надо отделить реализацию от интерфейса; в итоге получится столь же хрестоматийный «мост»:

```
abstract class CounterImpl {
  constructor() {}

  getData(data: number): number {
    return data;
  };
}

class ImpulseCounter extends CounterImpl {
  constructor(
    private initCounter: number,
    private multipler: number,
  ) { }

  getData(data) {
    this.initCounter + this.multipler * data;
  }
}

class DigitalCounter extends CounterImpl {
  constructor(
    private address: string,
  ) { }

  getData() {
    this.super.getData();
  }
}

abstract class Counter {
  constructor(protected serialNumber: string
    private impl: *CounterImpl
          ) { }

  getData(data: number): number {
    return impl->getData(data);
  };
}

class WaterCounter extends Counter {
  constructor(
    hot: bool
    serialNumber,
  ) {
    super(impl, serialNumber)
  }
  getData(data: number): number {
    return this.super.getData(data) * (this.hot ? 0.1 : 1);
  };
}
```

Comment: Я остановился на втором варианте. 
Только вместо CounterImpl (DigitalCounter) обозвал Channel. Ведь по логике импульс или цифровой, это способ получения данных из канала по которому считываются данные счетчика.  В этом случае как раз второй вариант ложиться хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

Определение типа в поле `type` это неправильно.

Тип должен определяться динамически или через наследование или через имплементацию интерфейса. Если 1-й у вас более-менее соответствует общепринятому шаблону проектирования, то через интерфейсы должно выглядеть приблизительно так:

```
interface Countable {
   public int getCountData();
}

class WaterCounter implements Countable {
   public int getCountData() {
      //blah-blah
   }
}
```

**P.S.** Не могу придумать случая, когда я бы лично использовал поле `type`... - скорее всего никогда. Ну или если тип такой ничтожный, что бессмысленно ради него генерить класс, хотя если тип недостоин класса, значит это не тип, а просто свойство - ну как пятнистая собака не является отдельным видом собак, это просто собака с пятнами :)